# What exactly is an "object" of serialization?

Tags: serialization

`object` in this context is not 'the goal' or 'intent'.

Serialization was quoted and I am interested in better understanding the use of the word `object`:

> Serialization is the process of converting an **object** into a stream of bytes to store the object or transmit it to memory, a database, or a file. Its main purpose is to save the state of an object in order to be able to recreate it when needed. The reverse process is called deserialization.
>
> ...
>
> This illustration shows the overall process of serialization
>
> [image: Overall process of serialization]
>
> ...
>
> Through serialization, a developer can perform actions like sending the object to a remote application by means of a Web Service, passing an object from one domain to another, passing an object through a firewall as an XML string, or maintaining security or user-specific information across applications

Is `object` (in the above context) to include (but not necessarily limited to) any real-world phenomena that one like to model?   For example:

As a concrete example is object of this narrative is a Broadway patron? or is it a revenue seat?

> A fictional Broadway show has 3 shows every Saturday. Tickets are
>   valid for a particular show and enumerated seat. The process of
>   encoding the `showtime` and serially enumerated `seat number` defines
>   a **unique** ticket.   Ticket are encoded with a barcode comprising
>   said data to measure attendance.

## Additional copied concrete example: Explanation via Picture:

[image: Rex, my dog, is serialised!]

### Explanation by Analogy:

Suppose I'm talking to my buddy on the phone and I'm telling him about my new puppy.

Here's my problem: the puppy is a living, breathing mammal. How am I meant to convey a puppy over the phone line? I can't physically put my puppy into my phone receiver.

So instead, I'll have to convey a representation of the puppy over the phone. In other words, I then serialize my dog Rex, and I send him the serialized version of Rex over the phone line:

`{ "name":"Rex", "age":5, "favourite_food": pedigree_choice_cuts, "favourite_game": fetch_ball, "favourite_hobby": wagging_tail }`

It's a perfect representation - a serialization of my dog.

#### Summary:

Serialization basically means transforming my dog Rex into something else - a JSON object - which can then be transported over the phone line as a series of 1s and 0s. My buddy in NYC can then translate those 1s and 0s back into a JSON object - so that he has a perfect representation of my dog Rex. Simple!

Answer (score 0):

It means any kind of composite data, e.g. an aggregate, a structure, a union, an array, or (in [object-oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) languages) some object (e.g. an [instance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_(computer_science)) of some [class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)), if your language have them; but you could have [prototype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming)-based programming languages, such as JavaScript).

Be also aware of [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). It makes binary data less portable than textual one.

Look into several [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) libraries for more. Start with simple things like RPC [XDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation), most [JSON](https://json.org/) libraries, etc. See also [s11n](http://www.s11n.net/)